# Is it possible to have universal constants in an R Markdown document?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Assume I have a long .Rmd document with chunks of R, Python and Bash code, which serves as a pipeline.

Now for usability I'd like to have a small constant section at the beginning of the document, so that people can modify some crucial parameters of the pipeline without having to dive through the whole document. Some of these parameters will be used in R, some of them in Python, and some of them in Bash chunks.

Is there any way in R Markdown to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not the best solution, but I've used [feather](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/03/29/feather/) to write data from R in one chunk and read it in Python in another chunk. It's written to be lightweight and fast for sharing between R and Python. I don't know about bash though

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem doing that for R code:  all chunks are run in a single session.

However, each Python and bash chunk is run independently of the others, so you'll need to explicitly save those variables to a file or perhaps an environment variable:  see the discussion here:  https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/222207188-Multiple-Python-chunks-in-RStudio-R-Markdown

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Do you know if there is a feature in the works that would allow for universal variables that can be transmitted through different environments?

Comment: The python engine in knitr has been changed in knitr 1.18: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/releases/tag/v1.18 All python code chunks will be executed in the same python session by default. More info: https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/r_markdown.html

Comment: Oh, that's really awesome, so it's only Bash left that's giving me some trouble then.

Comment: Yes, that's good news.  I wonder if someone at RStudio could add an update to the support forum thread I posted?

Comment: @YihuiXie However I'm noticing that it doesn't work if I'm using the "Run Current Chunk" command.

Assuming I have 2 separate chunks of python code, the second chunk will recognize the first chunk if I use the "knit" button or render function.

BUT it won't work if I run 2 chunks of python code independently using the green play button. Is this because this is not supported yet, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Michael https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/rstudio_ide.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! I jus tried using the `use_virtualenv("r-reticulate")` line, and now I get a very strange error. **This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "", Reinstalling the application may fix this problem**


Never seen this before, seems very weird. Is this something somebody here has come across before using Anaconda python for Windows R Markdown? (It's a plt.show() command that causes this, from matplotlib).